# How to have multiple event listeners with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made 2 scatter plots representing some dat with dropdowns that allow what data to be store on each axis in the two plots, I am trying to make multiple things happen, bruushing on one plot makes it so that the opacity of the corresponding dots on both graphs changes - this already works, when I click on an individual dot, the same /thing //happens - the dot on both graphs changes opacity, and the last thing I want to do is add a tool tip displaying the dots name, control and locale. I got the brushing feature to work, but no matter what I do I can't seem to add the other two features. Here is the commented javacript file:

````
    let fullDataset;
    let brushedData = [];
    let brushedSelection = null; // Initialize the global variable
    
    d3.csv("colleges_dataset.csv").then(function(data) {
    
        fullDataset = data;
    
        var regionCounts = d3.rollup(data, v => v.length, d => d.Region);
        
        // Convert the Map to an array of objects
        var regionsData = Array.from(regionCounts, ([Region, Count]) => ({ Region, Count }));
    
        // Set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var width = 930,
            height = 600;
    
        // Create a SVG for the bubble chart
        var svg = d3.select("#bubble-chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
    
        // Create a scale for bubble sizes
        var size = d3.scaleSqrt()
            .domain([0, d3.max(regionsData, d => d.Count)])
            .range([20, 110]); // Size in pixels
    
        // Create a color scale
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    
        // Initialize the circle: all located at the center of the svg area
        var node = svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(regionsData)
            .join("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", d => size(d.Count))
            .attr("cx", width / 2)
            .attr("cy", height / 2)
            .style("fill", d => color(d.Region))
            .style("fill-opacity", 1)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 0);
    
        node.append("title")
            .text(d => `${d.Region}: ${d.Count} schools`);
    
        
            
        // Initialize labels for the bubbles
        var label = svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(regionsData)
            .join("text")
            .text(d => d.Region)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
            .style("fill", "white");
            
    
        // Features of the forces applied to the nodes:
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(width / 2).y(height / 2)) // Attraction to the center of the svg area
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(0.1)) // Nodes are attracted one each other if value is > 0
            .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(.1).radius(function(d){ return (size(d.Count)+3) }).iterations(1)) // Force that avoids circle overlapping
    
        // Apply these forces to the nodes and update their positions
        simulation
            .nodes(regionsData)
            .on("tick", function(d){
                node
                    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
                    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
                label
                    .attr("x", d => d.x)
                    .attr("y", d => d.y);
            });
    
        // Stop the simulation after a while -- long enough to let it stabilize
        simulation.stop();
    
        // Manually tick the simulation 100 times
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();
    
        // Restart the simulation
        simulation.restart();
    
        node.on("click", function(event, d) {
            // Filter the dataset for the selected region
            var filteredData = fullDataset.filter(item => item.Region === d.Region);
            
            // Store the filtered data in a global variable or pass it to page 2's rendering logic
            // For now, we'll just log it to the console
    
            // Hide page 1 and show page 2
            d3.select("#page-1").style("display", "none");
            d3.select("#page-2").style("display", "block");
    
            // You can also update the page 2's title or any other elements as needed
            d3.select("#selected-region").text(d.Region);
    
            // Here you would also initialize the scatterplots for page 2, using `filteredData`
        });
    
        var svg1 = d3.select("#scatterplot-1");
        var svg2 = d3.select("#scatterplot-2");
    
        populateDropdowns();
        updateScatterplots(svg1, svg2);
        createLegend();
    
        document.getElementById('back-to-regions').addEventListener('click', function() {
            d3.select("#page-1").style("display", "block");
            d3.select("#page-2").style("display", "none");
        });
    });
    
    function findCorrespondingData(brushedData, otherData, xAttr, yAttr) {
        return otherData.filter(d =>
            brushedData.some(b => b[xAttr] === d[xAttr] && b[yAttr] === d[yAttr])
        );
    }
    
    
    function drawScatterplot(svgId, data, xAttr, yAttr, svg1, svg2, enableClick) {
        var svgWidth = 400, svgHeight = 400;
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 60 },
            width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
        // Create SVG container
        var svg = d3.select(`#${svgId}`).html('').append('svg')
            .attr('width', svgWidth)
            .attr('height', svgHeight)
          .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
    
        // Create scales for x and y
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, d => +d[xAttr]))
            .range([0, width]);
    
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, d => +d[yAttr]))
            .range([height, 0]);
    
        // Add the scales to the axes
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
    
        // Add a group for the x axis
        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);
    
        // Add a group for the y axis
        svg.append('g')
            .call(yAxis);
    
        // Color scale for private vs public schools
        var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(['Private', 'Public'])
            .range(['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e']); // Example colors: blue for private, orange for public
    
        // Plot the data points with color based on school type
        var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
    
        // Plot the data points with color based on school type
        var dots = svg.selectAll('.dot')
            .data(data)
            .enter().append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'dot')
            .attr('r', 3.5)
            .attr('cx', d => x(+d[xAttr]))
            .attr('cy', d => y(+d[yAttr]))
            .style('fill', d => colorScale(d.Control)) // Use the color scale
            .style('opacity', 0.4)
        
        console.log(dots);
        dots.on("click", function(event, d) {
        console.log('dot clicked');
                // Show the tooltip on mouseover
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
    
        // Assuming 'Name' is the unique identifier for corresponding dots
        const correspondingDot = d.Name;
    
        console.log(correspondingDot);
    
        // Update the other scatterplot based on the clicked dot's data
        if (svg1 && svg2) {
            svg1.selectAll(".dot")
                .style("opacity", function (d) {
                    return d.Name === correspondingDot ? 1 : 0.4;
                });
    
            svg2.selectAll(".dot")
                .style("opacity", function (d) {
                    return d.Name === correspondingDot ? 1 : 0.4;
                });
        }
        });
    
        // Add X axis label
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", width / 2)
            .attr("y", height + margin.bottom - 10)
            .text(xAttr);
    
        // Add Y axis label
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", -margin.left + 20)
            .attr("x", -height / 2)
            .text(yAttr);
    
        // Add a legend
        var legend = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'legend')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width - 120) + ',' + 20 + ')')
            .selectAll('g')
            .data(colorScale.domain())
            .enter().append('g');
    
        // Add click event handler for individual dots
        if (enableClick) {
            dots.on("click", function (event, d) {
                // Change opacity of the clicked dot to 1
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
    
                // Update the other scatterplot (if it exists)
                if (svg1 && svg2) {
                    var x0 = x(+d[xAttr]);
                    var y0 = y(+d[yAttr]);
    
                    // Update the other scatterplot based on the clicked dot's position
                    svg1.selectAll(".dot")
                        .style("opacity", function (d) {
                            var cx = x(+d[xAttr]);
                            var cy = y(+d[yAttr]);
                            return (cx === x0 && cy === y0) ? 1 : 0.4;
                        });
    
                    svg2.selectAll(".dot")
                        .style("opacity", function (d) {
                            var cx = x(+d[xAttr]);
                            var cy = y(+d[yAttr]);
                            return (cx === x0 && cy === y0) ? 1 : 0.4;
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    
        var brush = d3.brush()
            .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .on("start brush end", brushed);
    
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .call(brush)
            .classed("active-brush", false);
    
        // Define the brushed function
        function brushed(event) {
            if (!event.selection) {
                // If no selection, reset the opacity to 0.4 for all points
                svg.selectAll(".dot")
                    .style("opacity", 0.4);
                
                svg.classed("active-brush", false);
            } else {
                // Get the current brush selection
                var [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]] = event.selection;
    
                // Update the global brushed selection
                brushedSelection = event.selection;
    
                // Iterate over the circles and update their opacity
                svg.selectAll(".dot")
                    .style("opacity", function(d) {
                        var cx = x(+d[xAttr]);
                        var cy = y(+d[yAttr]);
                        return cx >= x0 && cx <= x1 && cy >= y0 && cy <= y1 ? 1 : 0.4;
                    });
                 //console.log('hi ' + svg1);
                // console.log(svg2);
                // Update the other scatterplot as well
                if (svg1 && svg2) {
                    //console.log('hi');
                    svg1.selectAll(".dot")
                        .style("opacity", function(d) {
                            var cx = x(+d[xAttr]);
                            var cy = y(+d[yAttr]);
                            return cx >= x0 && cx <= x1 && cy >= y0 && cy <= y1 ? 1 : 0.4;
                        });
    
                    svg2.selectAll(".dot")
                        .style("opacity", function(d) {
                            var cx = x(+d[xAttr]);
                            var cy = y(+d[yAttr]);
                            return cx >= x0 && cx <= x1 && cy >= y0 && cy <= y1 ? 1 : 0.4;
                        });
                }
                svg.classed("active-brush", true);
            }
        }
    }
    
    function populateDropdowns() {
        const attributes = [
            'Admission Rate',
            'ACT Median',
            'SAT Average',
            'Undergrad Population',
            '% White',
            '% Black',
            '% Hispanic',
            '% Asian',
            '% American Indian',
            '% Pacific Islander',
            '% Biracial',
            'Average Cost',
            'Expenditure Per Student',
            'Completion Rate 150% time',
            'Retention Rate',
            'Median Debt on Graduation',
            'Median Earnings 8 years After Entry'
        ];
    
        attributes.forEach(attr => {
            d3.selectAll('.axis-select').each(function() {
                d3.select(this).append('option')
                    .text(attr)
                    .attr('value', attr);
            });
        });
    
        // Optionally set default selected attributes for the scatterplots
        d3.select('#x-axis-select-1').property('value', 'Admission Rate');
        d3.select('#y-axis-select-1').property('value', 'SAT Average');
        d3.select('#x-axis-select-2').property('value', 'Admission Rate');
        d3.select('#y-axis-select-2').property('value', 'ACT Median');
    }
    
    function updateScatterplots(svg1, svg2) {
        const plotId1 = 'scatterplot-1';
        const plotId2 = 'scatterplot-2';
        drawScatterplot(plotId1, fullDataset, d3.select('#x-axis-select-1').property('value'), d3.select('#y-axis-select-1').property('value'), svg1, svg2, true);
        drawScatterplot(plotId2, fullDataset, d3.select('#x-axis-select-2').property('value'), d3.select('#y-axis-select-2').property('value'), svg2, svg1, true);
    }
    
    d3.selectAll('.axis-select').on('change', function () {
        // Get the updated selections
        var xAttr1 = d3.select('#x-axis-select-1').property('value');
        var yAttr1 = d3.select('#y-axis-select-1').property('value');
        var xAttr2 = d3.select('#x-axis-select-2').property('value');
        var yAttr2 = d3.select('#y-axis-select-2').property('value');
    
        // Store the references to svg1 and svg2 within the function scope
        var svg1 = d3.select("#scatterplot-1");
        var svg2 = d3.select("#scatterplot-2");
    
        // Update the scatterplots with the new selections
        drawScatterplot('scatterplot-1', fullDataset, xAttr1, yAttr1, svg1, svg2, true);
        drawScatterplot('scatterplot-2', fullDataset, xAttr2, yAttr2, svg2, svg1, true);
    });
    
    function createLegend() {
        var legendWidth = 200, legendHeight = 50;
        var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(['Private', 'Public'])
            .range(['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e']); 
    
        var svg = d3.select("#legend-container").append("svg")
            .attr("width", legendWidth)
            .attr("height", legendHeight);
    
        var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
            .data(colorScale.domain())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
    
        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", colorScale);
    
        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 45)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d`enter code here`; });
    }```
    
    How do I add the functionality for those 2 problems I have?
````